# donet pack in VS Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, dotnet-cli

I have a problem with my build configuration in VS Team Services.
I try to mark my nuget packages with prerelease suffix.

I have a Utility CommandLine step defined.

```
Tool: dotnet
Argument: pack $(build.sourcesdirectory)/..../project.json --no-build --configuration Release --output nupkgs --version-suffix "prerelease-$(rev:.rr)"
```

I get the message:
"'1.0.0-prerelease-$(rev:.rr)' is not a valid version string."

If I do the same with a static:

```
Tool: dotnet
Argument: pack $(build.sourcesdirectory)/..../project.json --no-build --configuration Release --output nupkgs --version-suffix "prerelease-123"
```

That works fine.

So, it seams that the special placeholder $(rev:.rr) is not replaced, but I don't know why.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there are different variables for the build and release tabs.
I tried to use this token on a build definition, what didn't work.

I was able to achive what I want to do with a build token.

Kind regards